# AsyncTask class VS AsyncTask object

Tags: java, android, performance, android-asynctask, inner-classes

Couldn't find the answer to the question that which of the following technique of using `AsyncTask` is better (performance wise, memory management, design wise)?

**OBJECT EXAMPLE**

```
class AsyncTaskObjectExample {

    protected AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> asyncTaskObject = new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            /* YOUR PROCESSES */
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

**CLASS EXAMPLE**

```
class AsyncTaskClassExample {

    class AsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            /* YOUR PROCESSES */
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both you mentioned are classes. The first one is Anonymous inner class. When you write this:

```
new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>() {
        @Override 
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            /* YOUR PROCESSES */ 
            return true; 
        } 
    };
```

This becomes an anonymous inner class which extends `AsyncTask`.

You can read here more about anonymous inner classes here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

You can try whatever is easier to understand for you.

Comment: do you know about memory leak?

Comment: I know about anonymous inner class. But you see, in class scenario, we are inheriting. That could mean something from memory management perspective. Also, we can make a function level object of `AsyncTaskClassExample` but `AsyncTaskObjectExample` can only be a class level object. Does this mean nothing?

Comment: @PareshMayani Pretty sure this is only an issue if you're passing an `Activity` and storing a reference to it in the task.

Comment: @PareshMayani ys I know. if the Activity has already been destroyed, it will still keep this reference in memory.

Comment: Also, both I mentioned are not classes, but are objects.
One with a class definition and its object and one with object only.

Comment: Okay thanks. So performance and memory have no impact. What about design? Which one do you prefer?

Comment: @BugsHappen The design should be according to the situation. It is good to use anonymous inner class. But If you need to cancel asynctask or check if it has been finished or not, you will still need a reference to call like asynctask.cancel() .If the AsyncTask does not need to keep a reference to the activity, you can declare it static nested class to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Oh yes, right. Because once you cancel `AsyncTask`, you cannot restart it without creating its new object. So `ObjectExample` will surely fail in this case. Thanks, I have got the idea.